# Reading each line of HTML table into python list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a HTML table using python.  I am using beautiful soup to do this web scraping. There are many tables in the HTML page and there are many rows in the table. I want each row to have a different name and if there are columns in the row, want them to be separate.

My code looks like this:

```
page = get("https://www.4dpredict.com/mysingaporetoto.p3.html")
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
result = defaultdict(list)
tables = html.find_all('table')
for table in tables:
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[0:15]:
        try:
            #stuck here
        except ValueError:
            continue  # blank/empty row
```

Need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your requirement, the following script should do the trick:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.4dpredict.com/mysingaporetoto.p3.html'

res = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
num = 0
for tables in soup.select("table tr"):
    num+=1
    data = [f'{num}'] + [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in tables.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

Partial output:

```
['1', 'SINGAPORE TOTO2018-08-23 (Thu) 3399']
['2', 'WINNING NUMBERS']
['3', '02', '03', '23', '30', '39', '41']
['4', 'ADDITIONAL']
['5', '19']
['6', 'Prize:$2,499,788']
['7', 'WINNING SHARES']
['8', 'Group', 'Share Amt', 'Winners']
['9', 'Group 1', '$1,249,894', '2']
['10', 'Group 2', '$', '-']
['11', 'Group 3', '$1,614', '124']
['12', 'Group 4', '$344', '318']
['13', 'Group 5', '$50', '6,876']
['14', 'Group 6', '$25', '9,092']
```

Comment: If you are using python's latest version, I doubt there is any error. Check out the ouput the script produces.

Comment: how to fix that?

Comment: Try this `['%s' % num]` replacing with `[f'{num}']`.

Comment: Then I failed to understand your requirement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the below code, let me know if that doesn't works,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
page = requests.get("https://www.4dpredict.com/mysingaporetoto.p3.html")
html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tables = html.find_all('table')
table_data = dict()
for table_id, table in enumerate(tables):
    print('[!] Scraping Table -', table_id + 1)
    table_data['table_{}'.format(table_id+1)] = dict()
    table_info = table_data['table_{}'.format(table_id+1)]
    for row_id, row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
        col = []
        for val in row.find_all('td'):
            val = val.text
            val = val.replace('\n', '').strip()
            if val:
                col.append(val)
        table_info['row_{}'.format(row_id+1)] = col
    pprint.pprint(table_info)
    print('+-+' * 20)

pprint.pprint(table_data)
```

Sample Output

```
[!] Scraping Table - 1
{'row_1': ['SINGAPORE TOTO2018-08-23 (Thu) 3399'],
 'row_10': ['Group 2', '$', '-'],
 'row_11': ['Group 3', '$1,614', '124'],
 'row_12': ['Group 4', '$344', '318'],
 'row_13': ['Group 5', '$50', '6,876'],
 'row_14': ['Group 6', '$25', '9,092'],
 'row_15': ['Group 7', '$10', '117,080'],
 'row_16': ['SHOW ANALYSISEVEN : ODD, 2 : 5SUM :138, AVERAGE :23 MIN :02, MAX '
            ':41, DIFF :39',
            'EVEN : ODD, 2 : 5',
            'SUM :138, AVERAGE :23',
            'MIN :02, MAX :41, DIFF :39'],
 'row_17': ['EVEN : ODD, 2 : 5'],
 'row_18': ['SUM :138, AVERAGE :23'],
 'row_19': ['MIN :02, MAX :41, DIFF :39'],
 'row_2': ['WINNING NUMBERS'],
 'row_3': ['02', '03', '23', '30', '39', '41'],
 'row_4': ['ADDITIONAL'],
 'row_5': ['19'],
 'row_6': ['Prize: $2,499,788'],
 'row_7': ['WINNING SHARES'],
 'row_8': ['Group', 'Share Amt', 'Winners'],
 'row_9': ['Group 1', '$1,249,894', '2']}
+-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-++-+
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest abandoning BeautifulSoup (beautiful though it is) and using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) (which uses BeautifulSoup or lxml on the back end). What you describe is bog standard with pandas, just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use requests.get() instead of get() method

Comment: Could you please use some of the OP code to enhance your answer? to make it clear what line of code will be the answer to OP question.

Comment: OP seems to have used `requests` library. However, he perhaps imported `get` from it like `from requests import get`. I still can't find any relevance between the answer to the question and your oneliner comment..

Comment: Thanks SIM for suggestion.. I am new to python as well as stack over flow. try to learning and solving ..